# Pairwise Fisher's Exact test

Tags: r, comparison, posthoc

I am comparing 3 treatments with success/failure response variable creating n x 2 for Fisher's exact test.  Now I want to do post hoc comparisons using pairwise.fisher.test (fmsb package).

```
success <- c(0, 0, 8)
failure <- c(80, 80, 8)
df <- data.frame(success, failure)
row.names(df) <- ("autogamy", "gietonogamy", "outcross")
```

To give:
success failure
autogamy          0      80
gietonogamy       0      80
outcross          8      72

The test.1 <- fisher.test(df) works fine with p < .05, but now I want to do a the post hoc, but get an error that 'x' and 'n' must be the same length.

```
pw.test <- pairwise.fisher.test(breedsystem.df, n = 2, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

I have tried multiple values of n, but all with the same error.  Any help appreciated to sort out n or try different methods.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 success <- c(0, 0, 8)
 failure <- c(80, 80, 8)
 total <- success + failure
 names(total) <- c("autogamy", "gietonogamy", "outcross")
 pairwise.fisher.test(success, total,p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

```
    Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions (Fisher) 

data:  success out of total 

  1       2      
2 1       -      
3 2.9e-07 2.9e-07

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

parameter `n=` should be the vector of total number of bernoulli trials, not the 3 trial conducted.  hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).